# How to save text from text box in text file?

Tags: c#, file, textbox

I have 3 text boxes and one button. On button click all text from text boxes should be written in text file (in one line). How can i do that?

Comment: What have you tried?  What specific steps are you having trouble with?

Comment: I used this:

string dest = @"I wrote destination here";
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(dest);
string s = tbID.Text + tbIme.Text + tbPrezime.Text;
sw.WriteLine();

Comment: Please do not post code in comments, update your question with code samples.

Answer (score 2):

Direct implementation:

```
    File.WriteAllText(dest,
      tbID.Text + tbIme.Text + tbPrezime.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have all textboxes in a `List<TextBox>` and at the time of writing do:

```
list.ForEach(tb => file.Write(tb.Text));
file.WriteLine();
```